If $\sup_{f\in F} \Big|||f||_n-||f|| \Big|\overset{p}{\to} 0$ then $\sup_{f\in F, ||f||\neq 0} \Big| ||f||_n/||f||-1 \Big| \overset{p}{\to} 0$.
SETUP:
Let $\{X\}_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a strictly stationary stochastic process on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ where for each $t\in\mathbb{N}$ the random elements are such that $X_t:\Omega\to\mathbb{X}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$.
Let $F$ be a class of measurable functions $f:\mathbb{X}\to\mathbb{R}$, and let $||\cdot||_n$ and $||\cdot||$ be (semi-) norms on $F$ where $||\cdot||_n$ may depend on a random sample $\{X_t\}_{t=1}^n$ (such as the sample average).
QUESTION:
Does it follow that
$$ 
\sup_{f\in F} \Big|||f||_n-||f||  \Big|\overset{p}{\to} 0 
\implies \sup_{f\in F, ||f||\neq 0} \Big| ||f||_n/||f||-1 \Big| \overset{p}{\to} 0
?
$$
(Assuming $F$ is such that the supremums above are measurable)
If it helps, the norms I had in mind are $||f||_n=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^n[f(X_t)]^2}$ and $||f||=\sqrt{E(f^2)}$.
MY ATTEMPT:
I tried to show this using the following, for $\delta>0$:
$$ 
\sup_{f\in F} \Big|||f||_n-||f||  \Big| < \delta
\implies 
\sup_{f\in F, ||f||\neq 0} 
\Big| ||f||_n/||f||-1 \Big|
=
\sup_{f\in F, ||f||\neq 0} 
\left| \frac{||f||_n - ||f||}{||f||} \right|
< 
\sup_{f\in F, ||f||\neq 0}\frac{\delta}{||f||}
$$
but this could be arbitrarily large if $||f||$ can be arbitrarily close to zero.

This fails for $F={0}$. I would expect that one needs a lower bound of $|f|$ on $F$, i.e., $\inf_{f\in F} |f|>0$ to prove the claim.
